# How to make "Less" link in one position after third items on list - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have list items with show more/less link. "More" link is in the fourth place and after clicking them, "Less" link is at the end of the list. I need "Less" link in one position - at the fourth place on the list like "More" link. The rest items of the list should be after "Less" link. Any ideas how can I make it?

My code:

```
<ul ng-if="::document.actUnitMonographViewList" class="commentary-snippets">
  <li ng-repeat="monograph in document.actUnitMonographViewList | limitTo: monograph.limit ? document.actUnitMonographViewList.length : 3">
  <i ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <a href="" ng-href="{{ ::getPublicationLink(monograph, 'monograph') }}" ng-class="{'arrow-link': document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1}" user-preferences-target>
      {{::monograph.title}}
    </a>
  </li>
  <li ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
    <i class="list-items-toggle-arrow" ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-up': monograph.limit, 'fa fa-chevron-down': !monograph.limit}" ng-click="monograph.limit = !monograph.limit"></i>
    <a ng-click="monograph.limit = !monograph.limit" class="list-items-toggle-link">{{monograph.limit ? 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.LESS' : 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.MORE' | translate}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- Now, "Less" link in the list items looks like:

  1. item
  2. item
  3. item
  4. item
  5. item
  6. item
  7. **Less**
- It should be in fourth place all the time:

  1. item
  2. item
  3. item
  4. **Less** (like "More" link)
  5. item
  6. item

Answer (score 0):

Try with using `ng-if` statement relating to `$index` of `ng-repeat` item.

```
<ul ng-if="::document.actUnitMonographViewList" class="commentary-snippets" ng-repeat="monograph in document.actUnitMonographViewList | limitTo: monograph.limit ? document.actUnitMonographViewList.length : 3">
  <li>
  <i ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <a href="" ng-href="{{ ::getPublicationLink(monograph, 'monograph') }}" ng-class="{'arrow-link': document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1}" user-preferences-target>
      {{::monograph.title}}
    </a>
  </li>
  <li ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
    <i class="list-items-toggle-arrow" ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-up': monograph.limit, 'fa fa-chevron-down': !monograph.limit}" ng-click="monograph.limit = !monograph.limit"></i>
    <a ng-if="$index == 3" ng-click="monograph.limit = !monograph.limit" class="list-items-toggle-link">{{monograph.limit ? 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.LESS' : 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.MORE' | translate}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a similar example :
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/UxxNV96TWPAUmIwc?preview

Comment: After that "Less/More" text disappeared and the link is still the last place of the list item.

Comment: @NataliaGurgul could you show all of your code? best example of how my plunker along with data and html content

Comment: function getPublicationLink (document, stateName){
    document.stateName = stateName;
    ListDecoratorService.addLink(document);
    return document.link;
}

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<ul ng-if="::document.actUnitMonographViewList" class="commentary-snippets">
  <li ng-repeat="monograph in document.actUnitMonographViewList | limitTo: document.monographLimit ? document.actUnitMonographViewList.length : 3">
    <i ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <a href="" ng-href="{{ ::getPublicationLink(monograph, 'monograph') }}" ng-class="{'arrow-link': document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1}" user-preferences-target>
      {{::monograph.title}}
    </a>
    <div ng-if="$index === 2" ng-click="document.monographLimit = !document.monographLimit" class="list-items-toggle">
      <i ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-up': document.monographLimit, 'fa fa-chevron-down': !document.monographLimit}" class="list-items-toggle-arrow"></i>
      <a class="list-items-toggle-link">{{document.monographLimit ? 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.LESS' : 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.MORE' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```